# Can I Use EF Core 5 InMemory Database For Integration Testing

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I'm working on migration from net core 3.1 to net 5 (EF Core 3 to EF Core 5 aswell). We are using EF Core 3 InMemory database for integration tests. After migration tests no longer passing and queries throw error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'ShapedQueryExpression:
> QueryExpression:
> InMemoryQueryExpression:
> ServerQueryExpression:
> InMemoryTableExpression: Entity: RatingExclusionProduct
> .Where(valueBuffer => IsFalse(ValueBufferTryReadValue(valueBuffer, 0, Property:
> RatingExclusion.Id (UUId) Required PK AfterSave:Throw).Equals(null))
> && object.Equals(
> objA: ExpressionExtensions.ValueBufferTryReadValue(
> valueBuffer: valueBuffer,
> index: 0,
> property: Property: RatingExclusion.Id (UUId) Required PK AfterSave:Throw),
> objB: ExpressionExtensions.ValueBufferTryReadValue(
> valueBuffer: valueBuffer,
> index: 0,
> property: Property: RatingExclusionProduct.ExclusionId (UUId) Required PK FK
> AfterSave:Throw)))
> ProjectionMapping:
> Member: EmptyProjectionMember Projection: EntityProjectionExpression:
> Property: RatingExclusionProduct.ExclusionId (UUId) Required PK FK AfterSave:Throw ->
> ExpressionExtensions.ValueBufferTryReadValue(
> valueBuffer: valueBuffer,
> index: 0,
> property: Property: RatingExclusionProduct.ExclusionId (UUId) Required PK FK
> AfterSave:Throw)
> Property: RatingExclusionProduct.ProductId (UUId) Required PK FK Index AfterSave:Throw ->
> ExpressionExtensions.ValueBufferTryReadValue(
> valueBuffer: valueBuffer,
> index: 1,
> property: Property: RatingExclusionProduct.ProductId (UUId) Required PK FK Index
> AfterSave:Throw)
> ,
>
> ```
> ShaperExpression: EntityShaperExpression: 
>         EntityType: RatingExclusionProduct
>         ValueBufferExpression: 
>             ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
>         IsNullable: False
>
> .AsQueryable()
> .LeftJoin(
>     inner: DbSet<ControlProduct>(), 
>     outerKeySelector: o0 => EF.Property<UUId>(o0, "ProductId"), 
>     innerKeySelector: c => EF.Property<UUId>(c, "Id"), 
>     resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<RatingExclusionProduct, ControlProduct>(
>         Outer = o, 
>         Inner = i
>     ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> ```
>
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'

Can we somehow fix thise issue or we need to switch to some another method of mocking the database? As far as I know there was breaking change:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#no-client-methods

Does my problem related to it? I've search online and some people suggesting to use real database for testing purposes, but I have concern that would be realy slow solution and we have multiple contexts that uses single database, so it would be hard to create database on test start. Some suggest to create context aggregation (single context that contains all entities for database creation purposes only), but I have no idea how to implement that. I think my question looks more like combination of consequental questions, but I'm kinda lost a bit on this topic. Thanks a lot for your attention.

**UPDATE:**
UUId is custom type, which is used as PK for all our tables.
To resolve it we use:

```
    services
        .AddDbContext<RatingsContext>(opt =>
            opt.AddRelationalTypeMappingSourcePlugin<UUIdTypeMapperPlugin>()
                .UseMySql(connectionString, mso => mso
                    .ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 29), ServerType.MySql)
                    .EnableRetryOnFailure()
                )
        );
```

Where UUIdTypeMapperPlugin:

```
public class UUIdTypeMapperPlugin : ITypeMappingSourcePlugin, IRelationalTypeMappingSourcePlugin
{
    public CoreTypeMapping FindMapping(in TypeMappingInfo mappingInfo)
    {
        return mappingInfo.ClrType == typeof(UUId) ? new UUIdTypeMapper() : null;
    }

    public RelationalTypeMapping FindMapping(in RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo)
    {
        return mappingInfo.ClrType == typeof(UUId) ? new UUIdTypeMapper() : null;
    }
}
```

And UUIdTypeMapper:

```
public class UUIdTypeMapper : RelationalTypeMapping
{
    private static readonly ValueConverter<UUId, byte[]> _converter
        = new ValueConverter<UUId, byte[]>(uuid => uuid.ToByteArray(),
            byteArray => new UUId(byteArray));

    protected UUIdTypeMapper(RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters) : base(parameters)
    {
    }

    public UUIdTypeMapper() : base(new RelationalTypeMappingParameters(
        new CoreTypeMappingParameters(typeof(UUId), _converter), "binary(16)")
    )
    {
    }

    protected override RelationalTypeMapping Clone(RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters)
    {
        return new UUIdTypeMapper(parameters);
    }

    public override string GenerateSqlLiteral(object value)
    {
        return $"0x{value}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `UUId`? Sounds like a custom type used as PK / FK, and most likely is causing the issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev i've updated my question in regard of you response

Comment: What do *you* mean by integration testing? Forget the "official" definition - the meaning changes based on your perspective. The in-memory provider is meant to ease unit testing as a **low** fidelity mock. It's just a dictionary so complex SQL operations just can't be emulated. The SQLite provider in memory-only mode is better but SQLite is simply too restricted to make it a good alternative to testing with the actual database product you want. It doesn't even have proper data types

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We use in memory database to test controllers of our WebAPI. Prior updating to EF Core 5 everything worked fine (we used EF Core 3 without any problems). I know that its is not the best solution, but we need some cheap fix preferably

Comment: That's not what I asked. *Why* are you using a custom UUID instead of **Guid** though? If our MySQL provider doesn't support GUIDs a) replace Oracle's provider with the [Pomelo provider](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) and b) map to Guid, don't create a new custom type. No provider knows how to handle your custom type

Comment: `migration from net core 3.1 to net 5` why 5 and not 6? [.NET 5 is not a long-term-support version and goes out of support in May 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). The next Lont-Term-Support version is .NET 6. If you migrate to 5 you'll have to migrate again in 6 months. .NET 6 is already supported in production and will be released [tomorrow at .NET Conf](https://www.dotnetconf.net/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UUId is some kind of our organisation standard. Most of the projects use it, so I think it will stay for now and there is not much I can do about it, but we use plugin converter for this type. Maybe we can somehow fix this plugin? It was working fine with EF Core 3. About .NET 6, as far as I know it is still in RC phase. We are planning to switch to it eventually.

Comment: @Fallingsappy that eventually is now. It became supported in production as soon as the first RC version was released. Tomorrow you'll be able to download and install the final version. .NET 5 goes out of support in 6 months.

Comment: Are you calling `.AddRelationalTypeMappingSourcePlugin<UUIdTypeMapperPlugin>()` when configuring in memory provider (`.UseInMemoryDatabase(...)`)?

Comment: Could you also provide the full source code of the plugin (`UUId` class/struct, custom `AddRelationalTypeMappingSourcePlugin` extension method and what it uses etc.) or provide a link if it is public NuGet package.

Comment: "some people suggesting to use real database for testing purposes" - I personally can only agree on that. Yes, it is much slower but in memory DB just does not behave the same way a real database does and therefore your integration tests cannot find important issues which will then in best case show up in manual testing but in worst case scenario it will occur in production for the first time.

I for myself have decided that the additional time it takes to run tests on a real database is a good investment (and saves time fixing issues after the code is already in production).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research I found that there is a pending issue on EF Core GitHub related to my problem and it is a bug.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24318

I think our team should switch to integration testing on a real database. There is a helpful link about it:
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/run-ef-core-integration-tests-in-a-repeatable-and-isolated-way-using-a-public-docker-image-with-a-e912a89c7bf4